# Connecting interal SATA HDD on eSATA connector

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata, esata

I had bought by mistake a cable that has SATA connector on one end and eSATA on the other.

My intention was it to have SATA connectors on both ends, so that I connect a normal SATA HDD on the motherboard.

I can't send it back because it was my mistake, the store page shows it's eSATA. So I'd like to know if the cable is useless or if I can still use it.

Can I use the eSATA connector on the HDD or the motherboard? Or does its eSATA male connector work only on an eSATA female connector?

In that case, if I use it on an eSATA connector on the motherboard, does it work on a normal SATA HDD externally if I use a SATA power cabe too?

Comment: https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/esata-usb-hybrid-port left or right?

Comment: That doesn't work in my case. A cable for such connector provides on the other hand a connector for both data and power SATA connectors. My cable has only data SATA. I need a separated SATA power connector. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its whatever the cable equivalent of a paperweight is - the physical connectors for esata and esatap are different from regular sata and the cables are fairly cheap.

In theory you *could* find a sata - esata 'bracket' and mount it externally (so you can go hard drive -> sata end -> esata end -> bracket socket -> PC) but unless you need full sata speed from a bare hard drive I see little point.

Comment: So it indeed doesn't work, right? I had found a bracket as you said, that has internal SATA male connector and external eSATA female connector, together with a molex. I'm looking now for a adapter/extensor male molex - male SATA power so I can use it.

Comment: Nope - hence the reference to paperweight.